# Safari background-color transition to transparent when fixed. Bug?

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, css-position, background-color

I have a problem transitioning background-color to transparent in Safari 12.1 (14607.1.40.1.4).

The code will not transition the background to transparent. Instead it flickers or does nothing att all when hovered.

The transitions seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox. And it does work in Safari aswell if

- The div is empty
- OR Position:fixed is removed
- OR The target background-color is set to a color (rgba transparency doesnt work though)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body{
            background-color:white;
        }
        .box{
            width:200px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:lightblue;
            transition:1s all;
            position:fixed;
        }
        .box:hover{
            background-color:transparent;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to transition a fixed divs background-color to transparent. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: I have Safari V. 11.1 and it seemed to work fine when I put it in a JS Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/f0vkrb7h/

Comment: Just tested in Browserstack to get to Safari V. 12 and still works fine. So sorry, can't help without replicating issue. but I would say using transparent might be it.. try using rgba as that is as specific as it can get. But I do see you said that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. Maybe its something specific with my setup (build/os/graphics-card)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just hit the same Safari bug and was very frustrated with it...

It seems that `position: fixed` and `background: transparent` don't work well together on Safari.

I ended up adding a div inside my "fixed" div and used that for my background color transition.

Comment: I ended up going with a similar solution. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: Where did you find the info about "position: fixed and background: transparent don't work well together on Safari". Can you please post a link to that resource?

Comment: I didn't find an official resource that describes the issue. I was creating a simple one page site at the time with a fixed header that changed background from a solid color to a color with opacity on scroll. It worked on every browser as expected but not on Safari. On Safari instead of a transparent background I got a white color with no opacity. When I applied the background style to an inner div of the fixed element it worked as expected.